# how to exclude a url in filtermapping

Tags: java, servlet-filters, web.xml, url-pattern

web.xml

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>SessionCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filter.SessionCheckFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionCheckFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/app/admin/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I'm trying to exclude the `/faces/app/admin/index.xhtml` only, is there any way to do this?

If there's no exclude a url patterin in web.xml, maybe I can manipulate the `doFilter()` method to exclude the url?

Comment: Another way : http://www.coderanch.com/t/169859/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/Filter-Exclude-url-pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
      public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
                     ServletResponse servletResponse,
                     FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,
                                                     ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;

           String path = request.getPathInfo();
          if ((path != null) && (!path.equals("your path")){
         // write filter logic
            }
     }
```

Try above code.

Comment: This doesn't work. What is the request object?

Comment: servletRequest only-- Can you post your web.xml and Filter Code

Comment: You need to change your answer. You are missing a cast to HttpServletRequest. That actually contains the getPathInfo() method.